# ffmpeg image concat file with different file extensions

Tags: shell, ffmpeg, command, ffmpeg-php

I've been working with ffmpeg and I have got it to work perfectly quite a few times, but as of recent I am running into an issue where all the images from my text file arent used.

My text file looks like -

```
ffconcat version 1.0
file 'gallery-house-77-west-55th-street-01.jpg'
duration 4.44
file 'img03.jpg'
duration 4.44
file 'inside.png'
duration 4.44
file 'placeholder.png'
```

(amount of files, file names and extensions will always vary)

And I've tried several combinations but as of now my ffmpeg function looks like --

```
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -safe 0 -f concat -i paths.txt -c:a copy -c:v libx264 \
-vf "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,fps=25,format=yuv420p" -vsync vfr -movflags +faststart -y output.mp4 2>&1');
```

When trying to run it, the video seems to convert but has various weird behaviors - sometimes only the middle file(image) in the list is shown or the first 2 only are shown/rendered.

The audio is playing correctly though.

I've tried setting the framerate for the input and I also tried setting it for the output but it leads to more strange behavior.

This is what is echoed when running my above ffmpeg command -

```
 libavutil      56. 15.100 / 56. 15.100
  libavcodec     58. 19.100 / 58. 19.100
  libavformat    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavdevice    58.  4.100 / 58.  4.100
  libavfilter     7. 18.100 /  7. 18.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
[mp3 @ 0xb46780] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from 'audio.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:00:19.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 48 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, mono, fltp, 48 kb/s
Input #1, concat, from 'paths.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 754x424 [SAR 72:72 DAR 377:212], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0xba25c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0xb710c0] using SAR=3393/3392
[libx264 @ 0xb710c0] using cpu capabilities: none!
[libx264 @ 0xb710c0] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0xb710c0] 264 - core 155 r2901 7d0ff22 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=22 lookahead_threads=3 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.13.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 3393:3392 DAR 377:212], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.19.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 22050 Hz, mono, fltp, 48 kb/s
[swscaler @ 0xb93140] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0xb93140] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speed loss
[mjpeg @ 0xb6e200] mjpeg: unsupported coding type (cd)
[mjpeg @ 0xb6e200] mjpeg: unsupported coding type (c8)
[mjpeg @ 0xb6e200] Found EOI before any SOF, ignoring
[mjpeg @ 0xb6e200] mjpeg: unsupported coding type (c7)
Error while decoding stream #1:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mjpeg @ 0xb6e200] invalid id 94
Error while decoding stream #1:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp4 @ 0xb6f8c0] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=28.0 Lsize=     179kB time=00:00:19.95 bitrate=  73.6kbits/s speed=44.1x    
video:58kB audio:117kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.446521%
[libx264 @ 0xb710c0] frame I:1     Avg QP:28.86  size: 58683
[libx264 @ 0xb710c0] mb I  I16..4: 21.2% 59.8% 19.0%
[libx264 @ 0xb710c0] 8x8 transform intra:59.8%
[libx264 @ 0xb710c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 50.5% 65.2% 31.6%
[libx264 @ 0xb710c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 10% 60%  3% 28%
[libx264 @ 0xb710c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 20% 27% 26%  4%  4%  4%  6%  4%  7%
[libx264 @ 0xb710c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 20% 33% 10%  5%  6%  5%  8%  5%  7%
[libx264 @ 0xb710c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 47% 34% 11%  8%
[libx264 @ 0xb710c0] kb/s:11736.60
```

Any ideas whats causing the image sequence to fail?

**EDIT**

After some more debugging I think it may be related to the fact that all the files dont have the same extension. How can I make it so that it doesn't have to be that way or is that already a default setting and the issue is else where?

**EDIT 2**

I can get it to work when all the image extensions are the same but when it gets to png or any other image extension it renders the movie but the movie stops (incomplete) when it gets to that frame. This happens when I -
1. place all the jpgs before the png
2. run the following command ----

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i paths.txt -c:v libx264 \
-vf "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart -y output.mp4 2>&1
```

So my last guess may be correct and it's because I am mixing multiple image extensions in my ffmpeg command.

How can I correct it so that it allows a mix of any image files?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. It's not so much the different extensions, but different codecs. In case of images, the extension tracks the codecs.

You'll have to convert all inputs to the same codec. I recommend PNG.